# Namespaced controller causes error in Rails-3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, controller

I am using ActsAsTaggableOn to add tagging to my application. In addition to the features i get from this gem, I would also like to add a TagsController and basically treat tags as any other resource in my app.

I have created tags_controller.rb which contains

```
class ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsController < ApplicationController
    # ...
end
```

and in my routes.rb i have added

```
resources :tags, :module => :acts_as_taggable_on
```

When I run `rake routes` i get

```
    tags GET    /tags(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
         POST   /tags(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
 new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
     tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
         PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
         DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"acts_as_taggable_on/tags"}
```

… which all looks reasonable to me.

However, when I hit localhost:3000/tags i get this error:

```
LoadError (Expected MyApp/tags_controller.rb to define TagsController)
```

If I try to evaluate `ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsController`in the console I get basically the same error:

```
LoadError: Expected MyApp/app/controllers/tags_controller.rb to define TagsController
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Rails expects modules and classes to be in their namespace's directory. So you should move your controller, views and helpers in an `acts_as_taggable_on` directory:

- `app/controllers/acts_as_taggable_on/tags_controller.rb`
- `app/views/acts_as_taggable_on/tags/index.html.erb`
- etc.

I'm not sure why you want this namespace. If you only want to create REST actions on an existing model, you can generate a `scaffold_controller`. For example:

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Tag name:string
```

Comment: Alas, it does not work to move the controller into a folder with the same name as the namespace. It causes an "uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsController" error.

Comment: I need the namespace, since the model (from a gem) is namespaced.

Answer (score 0):

Michaël is right about the directory structure for namespaced controllers.

That being said, a controller does not have to be in the same namespace as a model. On the contrary, you can have a controller named SomeController working with a model named SomeModel. Have you already tried to drop the namespace from the controller class and see what goes wrong?

Comment: If the controller is not in the same namespace as the model, routing doesn't work: edit_tag_path(@tag) causes an <pre>undefined method `acts_as_taggable_on_tag_path'</pre> error.

Comment: Did you also remove the `:module` parameter from routes.rb?

Comment: Yes. The problem as far as I am able to tell is that Rails uses the model name—including its namespace—to generate urls. Which is why it I figured that it was probably correct to have the controller in the same namespace as the model.

Comment: Rails does not use model names to generate urls. Instead the route helpers are created from what you define in routes.rb. Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023982/rails-3-tagging-problems-acts-as-taggable-on? The asker there also uses an unnamespaced controller and is able to use the route helpers just fine.

Comment: Rails doesn't use the model to create the path, but it does rely on the model name to find the method that creates the path. That is what causes error I mention in the first comment. If the model name and controller name don't correspond, this method doesn't exist (or rather: It does, but by a different name)

Comment: It also does not rely on the model name to create the path. All it does is call the to_param method on the object you pass to the route helper. Could you maybe look-up where in the code `acts_as_taggable_on_tag_path` is called (file name and line number)? This might help in isolating the issue.